# Laravel 4 display custom error pages only in production

Tags: laravel-4

Do I understand right: if I want to display custom pages for 403, 404 etc. errors I should check whether app.debug is set to false:

```
if (!Config::get('app.debug')) {
    App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
    {
        switch ($code) {
            case 403:
                return Response::view('errors.403', array(), 403);

            case 404:
                return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);

            case 500:
                return Response::view('errors.500', array(), 500);

            default:
                return Response::view('errors.default', array(), $code);
        }
        Log::error($exception);
    });
}
```

Because, if I set App::error handler without checking app.debug I'll always get these custom pages instead of detailed info

Am I right?

Comment: My first thought was to use [Laravel's environment configuration](http://four.laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration), but I could be wrong.

Comment: You want to say use App::environment() instead of app.debug variable to check that? I've just read about environments and it's amazing, I can automatically override app.debug variable in my production environment

Comment: You can also use `if (!App::environment('local'){}` or whatever you dev environment is called.

Comment: Usually I create simple function called isProduction() as a shortcut to App:environment('production') to make things easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just move the if statement into the app::error function. So that the error is always logged, and the custom error page is only shown when app.debug is false.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    if (!Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return Response::view('errors.index', $code);
    }
});
```

Comment: fix the syntax error, remove additional ')' in return statement.